# gdal: Pixelvalues to nodata

Tags: gdal

I have a GRD-File where all pixelvalues which are less than 0.05 should be converted to nodata.

I know how to do this with ArcMap, but the process should be done automatically, for example with cronjobs.

Is there a possibility to do that with gdal (maybe gdal_warp or gdal_translate)?

Comment: Rather gdal_calc.py http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html. Read the last example.